# How to use smooth-scroll from tailwindcss in React?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, tailwind-css, smooth-scrolling

I have created a one-page website using `tailwindcss` and `React`. In the prototype I use the `tailwindcss` class "scroll-smooth" and it works. In `React` the class "scroll-smooth" does not work, but what is the reason?

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scroll-behavior#basic-usage

When I click "Why" on Navigation i jump to the section "why" but not smoothly:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="relative">
        <div className="flex flex-col scroll-smooth">

          <HomeNav />

          <HomeHero />

          <section id="why" className="flex flex-col items-center px-6 pt-20">
            ...
          </section>
          <HomeFooter />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Solution:**

I think `TailwindCss` Class "scroll-smooth" it doesn't work on react. So I use the `NPM` package "react-scroll" with which it works great and I probably have less compatibility worries.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

Comment: Which browser are you using? The CSS `scroll-behavior` (used by `scroll-smooth`) is not supported by all browsers. See: https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior

Comment: I use the latest Firefox and Chrome browser :) And in my clean Tailwind Prototype it works, but not in my React app. Maybe it's a React specific problem. I am new to React ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)** working superb but We can still use `scroll-behavior: smooth` with `react` and `tailwindcss`. Here is my solution:

---

**Folder & File** structure:

[image]

**App.js** :

```
import "./App.css";
import AntyHero from "./components/AntyHero";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Hero from "./components/Hero";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <section id="header">
        <Navbar />
      </section>
      <div className="flex flex-col h-screen items-center justify-center additional gap-3">
        <h1 className="text-5xl">TailwindCSS & React.js</h1>
        <h2 className="text-3xl pb-5">smooth scrolling behavior</h2>
        <div className="flex gap-5 items-center justify-center text-2xl underline bg-white rounded-md p-2">
          <a href="#one" className="text-orange-600">
            Section One
          </a>
          <a href="#two" className="text-red-600">
            Section Two
          </a>
          <a href="#three" className="text-green-700">
            Section Three
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="text-center text-3xl">
        <section id="one" className="h-screen bg-orange-600">
          Section One
        </section>
        <AntyHero />
        <section id="two" className="h-screen bg-red-600">
          Section Two
        </section>
        <Hero />
        <section id="three" className="h-screen bg-green-700">
          Section Three
        </section>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.css** :

```
@tailwind base;
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Output**:

[image]

*Tested with:"tailwindcss": "^3.0.11", "react": "^17.0.2"* *Firefox and Chrome*

Comment: Yes you are right when i add it to base layer than works ;)

But for now, I will use my solution via the react-scroll package.

Thanks!

Comment: @GregorWedlich You're welcome ! React-scroll is marvelous ;-)  Best regards and Thank You...

Comment: Thank you big time! You just saved me from having to install a bunch of packages ;0

Answer (score 5):

Add `scroll-behavior: smooth` to the code works for me.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "scroll-smooth" to the html tag worked for me. I am using react with next.js.

```
return (
    <html lang="en" className="h-full scroll-smooth">
      ...body
    </html>
  );
```